# SignalR messages are delayed on Windows Phone app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, signalr

I'm using SignalR to send messages between a website and a Windows Phone app (Windows Phone 8.0, silverlight).

In the Windows phone app, I use the SignalR client from Nuget `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client`, it seems to work fine to send messages, but it takes several seconds to receive them.

```
this.connection = new HubConnection("http://myapp.azurewebsites.net/");
this.theHub = connection.CreateHubProxy("myHub");
await connection.Start();
this.theHub.On<String>("message",
            string=>
                {
                    // Here I receive the message very late
                });
```

On the javascript side, messages arrive without delay.

Is there anything to configure on Windows Phone ?

Comment: No nothing should need configured for a Windows Phone in particular. If you can I would enable logging "connection.logging = true;" , and see what the hub is doing client side.

Comment: Try using a different transport (e.g. long polling) and see if it helps. I think I have seen a bug about messages being delayed by a few secs when using the default transport on the phone.

Comment: Yes, adding a long polling transport when starting the connection solved the problem. Now it's ok 
 await connection.Start(new LongPollingTransport());

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to use a Long polling transport, because the default transport delayed the messages.

The transport can be set when startig the connection :

```
await connection.Start(new LongPollingTransport());
```

as said in the comment below, a WebSocket transport is probably better

```
await connection.Start (new WebSocketTransport());
```

Comment: Maybe the WebSocket transport is better, and if you set it manually, it will be fast as LongPolling. So, try this: await connection.Start (new WebSocketTransport());

Comment: I can't test right now, but according to msdn, WebSockets are not supported on Windows Phone http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/supported-platforms

Comment: I tried it yesterday and it seems good, but you can check it. With the default value (empty) was slow. When I have found this answer (LongPollingTransport) I tried it, and change to WebSocketTransport. Both work fine.